# jQuery - how to make side navigation with appearing/disappearing text smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side nav containing four dots. When you hover over one of the dots, text appears next to each one. If you move the mouse between dots, the text flickers in and out of view. Is there a way to add some sort of functionality so if the user has not hovered over one of the dots in 1.5 seconds, then the text will hide the?

Code Snippet:

```js
function setNav(line,text) {
      $(text).hide();
      $(line).hover(
      function () {
        $(text).fadeIn(250);
      },
      function () {
        $(text).fadeOut(250);
      })
    }

    setNav(".lineDot", ".lineText");
```

```css
.dot {
      color: #000;
      display: inline;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .dot:hover {
      transform-origin: right;
      transform: scale(1.5);
    }

    .dots {
      position: fixed;
      right: 15px;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .lineDot {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dots">
    <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d1"><p id="d1text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">Home </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d2"><p id="d2text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">About </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d3"><p id="d3text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">Projects </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d4"><p id="d4text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">Contact </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
    <br>
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you clarify it? What has to be hidden?

Comment: When you hover over one dot and move the cursor to another, the text fades out and back in immediately. I would like to see if there is a way to solve this.

Comment: Ideally the user should be able to mover the cursor along the line of dots without the text fading in and out

Comment: The chosen solution makes no difference in FF, rather use the .stop() method, i.e.: .stop().fadeIn(250); .stop().fadeOut(250);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing this line of code?

```
setNav(".lineDot", ".lineText");
```

With this another one?

```
setNav(".dots", ".lineText");
```

That won't make the dots flick, because it's the element that contains the text what's showed at once.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the text to disappear while moving between the links you should listen for the parent element `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` or use `hover`, which is a shorthand I just prefer using it as it is more readable.

Apart from that, you are binding the hover every time you are calling the function which is not a good idea move it outside the function.

see a modified version of the above

```js
var text = '.lineText';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(text).hide();
  $('.dots').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $('.lineText').fadeIn(250);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $('.lineText').fadeOut(250);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dot {
  color: #000;
  display: inline;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.dot:hover {
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.dots {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}

.lineDot {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dots">
  <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d1">
    <p id="d1text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">Home </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d2">
    <p id="d2text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">About </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d3">
    <p id="d3text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">Projects </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="" class="lineDot" id="d4">
    <p id="d4text" class="lineText" style="display: inline;">Contact </p><i class="dot fas fa-circle"></i></a>
  <br>
</div>
```